# For loop help c++ college

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to understand how this following code runs without any infinite loops.

```
int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    for (;count <= 5; count++)
    {
        int count = 1;
        cout << count << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google scoping, and name hiding

Comment: You should [enable warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx#To-set-the-compiler-option-in-the-Visual-Studio-development-environment) on your compiler, it would tell you about the name hiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner `int count = 1` in the loop's body declares a new variable with a value of 1, which is distinct from the loop's `count`.

Comment: There are two `int count = 1` lines; you should probably clarify you mean the inner one.

Comment: @DanielH Good point. I hadn't noticed. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok, so the count in my for loop is different from the count inside the loop? is that caused by the for(;  part? really confusing me

Comment: `for(;` just means that the initialization part does nothing. This is because the variable is already initialized just before. You could move the preceding `int count = 1` there with no impact on the logic (`for(int count = 1; count <=5; count++)`). This has nothing to do with why the loop ends. It ends because the inner `int count = 1;` makes a new variables and doesn't impact the outer `count` in any way.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but if I move the ;  to the end of the for loop  for(count <=5; count ++;)  I then get an infinite loop.

Comment: @DarrenSkerrett  A `for` loop is always written `for([init]; [condition]; [increment])` where `[init]` is called once at the start, `[condition]` which determines when the loop ends and `[increment]` which is called after every iteration. When you move the `;` your initialization is `count <=5` (which does nothing), your condition is `count++` (which is always true since `count` is never 0) and then the increment operation is empty (does nothing). Since your loop's condition is always true, your loop never ends, until `count` overflows and it becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you very much. makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 3):

The variables `count` are not the same, they have different scopes:

```
int count = 1; ///--------------- Scope 1
for (;count <= 5; count++)
{ ///---------------------------- Scope 2
    int count = 1;
    cout << count << "\n";
} ///---------------------------- End Scope 2
///------------------------------ End Scope 1
```

So the `int count = 1` in Scope 2 is used in the `cout` because it is resolved as the lowest level scope. But one the for loop scope is finished, this count is destroyed and the count declared in scope 1 is used. This is why you dont get an infinite loop.

Comment: if having a hard time understanding why changing the loop to  for(count <=5; count++;)   would then give an infinite loop.

Comment: @DarrenSkerrett Because then your exit condition is `count++` which will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

The second count is not the same as the first count. You declare a new variable with a new memory address. Say that the memory address for the first count is a. The memory address for the second count is then b. So a variable at memory address b is equal to 1, but it does in no way affect the count at address a. You can check this by writing cout << &count << "\n" both before and after you declare a new count. This will give you their memory address.